# Have Isotope resize height of container after layout

Tags: html, css, jquery-isotope

I have a site with a bunch of objects (DIVs), and I'm using Isotope and the `fitColumns` mode to fit them on the page. I'd like to have Isotope fit as many objects as it can in the height of the container (as it always does), and then shrink the container height down to the bottom of the tallest column.

For example: if I have a bunch of objects that are each 400px tall and my container is set at 1000px tall, Isotope will only be able to put two objects in each column (which is fine). But the container height will be set at 1000px, which leaves me with 200px of extra space at the bottom that I don't want. Instead, I want Isotope to shrink the container height down to 800px. It should do the best job it can fitting the objects in the columns, and then bring the overall container height up to hug the bottom of the objects. Make sense?

I can't figure out a way to do this, since the `fitColumns` layout method requires that I specify the height of the enclosing container (thus setting a fixed height). How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution- switched to `masonry` mode and made sure `resizesContainer: true` was in there.

Comment: I think it's `resizeContainer: true` — (without the '_s_')